# Изменить значение одного свойства из другого свойства

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Добрый день!

Есть два поля textbox для ввода стоимости и скидки. Общая сумма пусть будет 1000. При вводе значения в поле стоимости должно меняться значение в поле скидки. И наоборот, при вводе скидки меняется значение стоимости.

В xaml файле сделал привязку к свойствам:

```
<TextBox Width="120"
         Height="23"
         Margin="214,52,0,0"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Text="{Binding TotalBalance,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                        Mode=TwoWay}"
         TextWrapping="Wrap" />
<TextBox Width="120"
         Height="23"
         Margin="77,52,0,0"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Text="{Binding Discount,
                        Mode=TwoWay,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
         TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Сами свойства описал следующим образом:

```
   public double? TotalBalance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_totalbalance.GetValueOrDefault() == 0)
            {
                _totalbalance = 1000;
            } 
                return _totalbalance;
        }
        set
        {
            _totalbalance = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TotalBalance");
            Discount = 1000 - value;
        }
    }

    public double? Discount
    {
        get
        {
            if (_discount.GetValueOrDefault() == 0) {
                _discount = 0;
            }
            return _discount;
        }

        set
        {
            _discount = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Discount");
            TotalBalance = 1000 - value;
        }        
    }
```

В результате получается зацикливание, т.к. одно свойство меняет второе, а второе сразу же меняет первое и понеслось..

Подскажите в какую сторону думать. Какое дополнительное условие нужно выполнить и каким образом. Желательно используя паттерн MVVM, т.к. пытаюсь его изучить.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
public double TotalBalance
{
    get { return _totalbalance ?? 1000; }
    set
    {
        _totalbalance = value;
        RecalculateDiscountFromBalance();
        RaisePropertyChanged("TotalBalance");
    }
}

public double Discount
{
    get { return _discount ?? 0; }
    set
    {
        _discount = value;
        RecalculateBalanceFromDiscount();
        RaisePropertyChanged("Discount");
    }        
}

void RecalculateDiscountFromBalance()
{
    _discount = 1000 - TotalBalance;
    RaisePropertyChanged("Discount");
}

void RecalculateBalanceFromDiscount()
{
    _totalBalance = 1000 - Discount;
    RaisePropertyChanged("TotalBalance");
}
```

Выделите общие подфункции в отдельные функции по вкусу.